# Array of reg_id for sending gcm from mysql using php

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send gcm to first 10 users in the database.

I get the following error when trying to do that:

> "registration_ids" field is not a JSON array

Below is my function to get gcm_id

```
 function getAllRegIds() {
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'android', 'android');

    if ($conn -> connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
    }

    $queryString = "select gcm_id FROM user";

    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $queryString);

    $regids = array();
    foreach($results as $row) {
        $regids[]=$row['gcm_id'];
    }
    return regids;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to something that uses while loop like the code below

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) 
{
  $regids[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **array_push**:

```
function getAllRegIds() {
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'android', 'android');

    if ($conn -> connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
    }

    $queryString = "select gcm_id FROM user";

    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $queryString);

    $regids = array();
    foreach($results as $row) {
        array_push($regids, $row['gcm_id']);
    }
    return regids;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your `playload` to `GCM`, the `registration_ids` key is for an array of Ids, you need to make sure it is an  array:

```
$regids = array();
$regids = getAllRegIds();
if(is_array($regids)){
    $fields = array(
            'registration_ids'  => $regids ,
            'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
    );
}else{
   echo "It is not an array";
}
```